# Where can I find the list of syscalls on 64bit assembly for linux?

Tags: linux, assembly, kernel, system-calls

I'm looking for the list of syscall for 64bit linux. Have any docs/sources links on syscalls for 64bit assembly?

Answer (score 2):

If you are on the Linux machine, then open a terminal (press CTRL-ALT-T) and type `man syscalls`. Scroll down to find the list!

Otherwise, you can just look here for an online replica:
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html